# How to calculate Heap free percent in Oracle weblogic using command line

Tags: oracle, free, heap-memory, weblogic12c

Can anyone help me find out Weblogic Heap Free Percent i.e. **39**(shown in image) using command line or if there is any code to find out the same.
[Heap Size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j81zY.png)

Comment: Is that suiting your requirement: http://weblogic-wonders.com/weblogic/2010/11/13/wlst-script-to-monitor-throughput-and-heapsize-of-weblogic-server/ ? Also, I found the official docs for monitoring the JVM with a script: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24491/monitoring.htm#WLSTG229

Comment: hey... Thank you so much...It worked...:-)